# Why is the Touchpad tab missing?

Tags: 12.10, touchpad, dell-vostro, alps

So my Dell Vostro 3360 came out of the box with an Alps touchpad which was detected as PS/2. Through [these steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109345/no-touchpad-tab-under-mouse-and-touchpad-settings-detected-as-ps-2-generic-mo), I was able to get as far as it appearing to be recognized as a touchpad. Howevver, I do not get the Touchpad tab in the Mouse/Touchpad settings. Two-finger scrolling appears to work, and the Fn-F3 does disable the touchpad, but the settings are so brutal that it is almost impossible to work with. Very difficult to scroll at all accurately. I'm hoping there's some settings which can be tweaked which will help with this.

Any ideas?

My xinput listing is as follows:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ GlidePoint Virtual Touchpad               id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Thanks,

Comment: You could experiment with the xinput command to change settings of your device see `xinput --help` for more details.

Comment: A good answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/205914/27968

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after fiddling around some, I was finally able to get it working. I had to reinstall Ubuntu, though.

After compiling and installing [this psmouse dklm](http://www.dahetral.com/public-download/psmouse-alps-dst-1.1.tbz/view), my touchpad was detected correctly, and the Mouse/Touchpad settings has a Touchpad tab for me to tinker with all the settings.

Hopefully this will make its way into the kernel sooner rather than later.

Comment: This page does not seem to exist…

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the "Synaptiks" software from the Software Center?

Comment: Synaptiks says "No Touchpad Found" which jives with the fact the Mouse/Touchpad settings doesn't have a Touchpad tab.