# Elantech touchpad stopped working after restart

Tags: touchpad, elantech

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 on my MSI X460DX notebook for a few weeks. Touchpad worked without problem. 2-finger scrolling worked as well as disabling touchpad with key shortcut. But now after a restart touchpad just stopped working completely. System Settings->Mouse and Touchpad->Touchpad tab was not here
So I tried to run `sudo modprobe psmouse` and than it started working, but the touchpad settings still aren't here and neither edge scrolling nor 2-finger scrolling is working. I also can't disable it.
I found out, that the touchpad is recognized as PS/2 Generic Mouse instead of my elantech touchpad.

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ A4TECH USB Device                         id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ A4TECH USB Device                         id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Is there a way how can I get my touchpad working properly as before?

Comment: Check out this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/109345/no-touchpad-tab-under-mouse-and-touchpad-settings-detected-as-ps-2-generic-mo?rq=1

Comment: I tried everything I found there, but nothing worked, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Same issue on Kubuntu. Just restarted my Dell after 30+ days. 1. Touchpad does work, but tapping on it doesn't register as a click which it did before. 2. Trying to open the touchpad settings crashes the settings app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution! I found it here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/667707 and a workaround from comment #3 worked.

```
sudo rmmod psmouse
sudo insmod /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/input/mouse/psmouse.ko
```