# Elantech toupad detected as PS/2

Tags: mouse, touchpad

My touchpad is detected as a mouse so no scrolling is possible.

- laptop Asus G550JK, Xubuntu 14.04.2
- dkms installed
- xinput gives me "PS/2 Generic Mouse" where Elantech Touchpad should be
- my touchpad seems to be ETD0105
- already tried this

  > sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
- and this

  > sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xserver-xorg
- and this

  > sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
- and tried to reconfigure driver according to this

  > https://hardc0l2e.wordpress.com/2014/12/06/fix-for-elantech-touchpad-on-ubuntu-14-04/
- `dkms status` gives me

  > focaltech, 1.5~trusty1: added
  >   psmouse, elantech-x551c, 3.19.0-30-generic, x86_64: installed
  >   vboxhost, 4.3.30, 3.19.0-30-generic, x86_64: installed

Any help would be truly appreciated :-) Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure it is Elantech? What does `dmesg | grep pnp` show?

Comment: @Pilot6 It shows this:
 [    0.244800] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.245070] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    0.245193] pnp 00:06: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs ETD0105 SYN0a00 SYN0002 PNP0f03 PNP0f13 PNP0f12 (active)
[    0.245218] pnp 00:07: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs ATK3001 PNP030b (active)
[    0.245708] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 10 devices

I'm absolutely sure that there was Elantech Touchpad before I updated couple of things (graphical driver, boot settings, apt-get autoremove etc.).

Comment: It is an really an Elantech

Comment: What is the kernel version `uname -r`?

Comment: 3.19.0-30-generic

Comment: It should work out of the box on that kernel. That is weird

Comment: @PIlot6 Yeah, that's what I say :-)

Comment: Please add output of `dkms status` TO YOUR QUESTION. Please do not add information to comments. It is unreadable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the right solution that @jandurek pointed out [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237059/elantech-touchpad-stopped-working-after-restart?rq=1).

```
sudo rmmod psmouse
sudo insmod /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/input/mouse/psmouse.ko
```

I added this to a startup script to enable two-finger scrolling right after ubuntu starts.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is very clear. You installed a wrong Focaltech touchpad driver.

And it is installed from my PPA. Remove it this way:

```
sudo apt-get purge focaltech-dkms
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/focaltech-dkms
```

Then reboot.

The touchpad should work without any driver.

So also remove the Elantech one too by:

```
sudo dkms remove psmouse/elantech-x551c --all
```

If the touchpad does not work, then re-install the Elantech driver. I am not 100% sure that this specific model works on kernel 3.19.

Comment: I removed the focaltech driver, rebooted (didn't work), then removed elantech driver and rebooted and still it's not working.

Installed driver with 
> sudo dkms install psmouse/elantech-x551c
And it's still not working. Damn it.

Comment: So install the elantech driver again.

Comment: Should I use another install command, Pilot?

Comment: Well, you installed that `psmouse-elantech-x551c.tar.gz`. So try it again. But I am not quite sure that it is good for your model.

Comment: No luck. I even tried what I found here (exactly my laptop): http://snakelab.cc/2015/01/09/running_ubuntu_on_asus_n550jk.html

Comment: Asus laptops can have various types of touchpads on same models. You need to find a solution addressing your specific one `ETD0105`.