# Turn off my touchpad Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, shortcut-keys, touchpad

I am not a fan of the trackpad/touchpad and I want to turn it off while using Ubuntu and I can't figure out how. I have a Dell Inspiron N5110 running Windows 8 with a dual boot option of Ubuntu 12.10.

The Dell Touchpad Properties show:

```
 "Driver"
Driver Provider:  Alps
Driver Date:  7/12/12
Driver Version: 8.1200.101.209
Digital Signer: Microsoft Windows Hardware Compatibility publisher

 "General"
Device type: Mice and other pointing devices
Manufacturer: Alps Electric
Location: plugged into PS/2 mouse port
```

In Windows 8 the Fn shortcut is <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and that works but in Ubuntu it does not, even though a red box appears in the top right corner indicating it may have. It shows a trackpad icon with an X when the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key are pressed.

When I go into system settings, there is only a tab for mouse and nothing for the touchpad.

I've tried several methods listed here and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making several suggested changes, many of  which didn't work. I am very new to Linux and Ubuntu 12.10, I ran across this post, [No "Touchpad Tab" under Mouse and Touchpad settings. Detected as PS/2 Generic Mouse](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109345/no-touchpad-tab-under-mouse-and-touchpad-settings-detected-as-ps-2-generic-mo?lq=1)

The statement entered into terminal as:
  sudo modprobe -r psmouse
worked. My trackpad is now completely disabled and I am so glad!

Comment: The command: sudo modprobe -r psmouse works in terminal and it does disable my touchpad. It seems to be detected as a PS/2 mouse but it works. Unfortunately I have to enter this command in terminal each time I start Ubuntu. I will now look for a way to add it to the boot process so it becomes automatic.

Comment: I found an answer to turn it off every time as Ubuntu boots. You can try it here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221757/run-automatically-program-on-startup-under-linux-ubuntu

Comment: The actual script I used is: sudo modprobe -r psmouse

Answer (score 1):

The following methods will ensure your changes persist as long as you use `gnome`:

**Using GUI (`dconf-editor`)**

1. Install and run `dconf-editor` (if you're on 12.10, `dconf-editor` might be pre-installed):

   `$ sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`

   `$ dconf-tools`
2. Go to the following settings directory:

   `org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals`
3. Under `touchpad`, uncheck the `touchpad-enabled` checkbox.

**Command-line**

If you prefer not to meddle with `dconf-editor`'s GUI, run the following command instead:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled false
```

Comment: Using GUI dcon-editor did not work and neither did the command line in terminal. I can not get the thing to turn off.

Comment: I guess your touch pad isn't recognized as a touch pad, and was instead recognized as a regular PS/2 mouse. I see you've solved your problem. You should mark your own answer as the solution to your question!

Answer (score -1):

Check in the Setting, under Keyboard, Shortcuts. Here you can browse to any number of features and enable them to your chosen key combinations. Trackpad is under System, Hardware.

Comment: -1 for not reading the question carefully. The OP has mentioned that "When I go into system settings, there is only a tab for mouse and nothing for the touchpad. " Besides, this question has accepted an answer already.